# Exotic Geometries

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I only recently realised there are more geometries than euclidean, spherical, hyperbolic and mix of them. 
But the wikipedia page on [The eight Thurston geometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture#The_eight_Thurston_geometries) in 3 dimensions is cryptic to me. I'm looking for nice references that describe metric spaces with associated geodesics and properties for the geometry of the universal cover of $SL(2, R)$, the Nil geometry and the Solv geometry.
With drawings !

For example, the book of J. Ratcliffe *'Foundations of hyperbolic manifolds'* is a nice start for hyperbolic geometry, I'd like something similar for those exotic geometries.

Comment: Related question with maybe interesting answers http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1531772/88985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*The Shape of Space*](http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/the-shape-of-space) by [Jeffrey Weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_Weeks_%28mathematician%29).

Answer (score 5):

If you want drawings, you need to see our recent work!

In HyperRogue 11.2 you can explore all the eight Thurston geometries.

See the [blogpost](http://zenorogue.blogspot.com/2019/09/hyperrogue-112-thurston-geometries-free.html) for a simple description and some videos, and the [geometries](http://www.roguetemple.com/z/hyper/geoms.php) page for a longer description with some references. The easiest way to play (in 11.2b) is: menu -> special modes -> racing -> racing in Thurston geometries.

Also see [a related question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24572/drawing-of-the-eight-thurston-geometries).

Answer (score 0):

*Three dimensional geometry and topology* by **William P Thurston** is a nice book with drawings

Answer (score 0):

Also I'd point out [this recent article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.12772) where the Thurston geometries are rendered from within!